# Вычисляемое поле в DataTable, возвращающее разницу в днях

Tags: c#, ado.net

Собственно вопрос описан в заголовке.

Имею `DataTable`, на этапе создания таблицы хочу доабвить в неё поле, в котором автоматом будет рассчитываться разница в днях между сегодняшним днём и датой, указанной в строке таблицы в поле Дата.

Возможен ли вообще такой вариант? Или вычисляемые поля позволяют производить только более простые операции с полями?

```
dtTrips.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));           
dtTrips.Columns.Add("able_to_earn_in", typeof(int));
dtTrips.Columns["able_to_earn_in"].Expression = String.Format("{0}-date", DateTime.Now);
```

примерно так пробовал

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643752/defining-datediff-for-a-calculated-column-in-a-datatable